# Join two tables in MySQL, have just one row in the result set with few columns selected from second table

Tags: mysql, join, row

I am having a challenge to achieve the following

Have 2 tables namely Transaction Table and Transaction_Event_LOG_INFO table

**Transaction Table Details**

| SL | TXN_ID | TXN_FOR | TXN_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | Shopping | Debit |
| 2 | 112 | Rent | Debit |

**Transaction_Event_LOG_INFO table**

| SL | TXN_ID | EVT_ID | EVT_CODE | EVT_CREATED_DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 200 | 100 | 11-12-2020 12:00:00 |
| 1 | 111 | 201 | 101 | 11-12-2020 12:01:00 |
| 1 | 111 | 202 | 102 | 11-12-2020 12:02:00 |
| 1 | 111 | 203 | 103 | 11-12-2020 12:03:00 |
| 1 | 111 | 204 | 104 | 11-12-2020 12:04:00 |
| 1 | 112 | 205 | 100 | 11-12-2020 12:05:00 |
| 1 | 112 | 206 | 101 | 11-12-2020 12:06:00 |
| 1 | 112 | 207 | 102 | 11-12-2020 12:07:00 |
| 1 | 112 | 208 | 103 | 11-12-2020 12:08:00 |
| 1 | 112 | 209 | 104 | 11-12-2020 12:09:00 |

I need to join the above two tables based on TXN_ID (which is unique)  and have just one row for every TXN ID and having all columns from 1st table and just the EVT_CREATED_DT from 2nd table like where EVT_CODE=100 and 104

like below

| SL | TXN_ID | TXN_FOR | TXN_TYPE | EVT_CREATED_DT_FOR_100 | EVT_CREATED_DT_104 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | Shopping | Debit | 11-12-2020 12:00:00 | 11-12-2020 12:04:00 |
| 2 | 112 | Rent | Debit | 11-12-2020 12:05:00 | 11-12-2020 12:09:00 |

Comment: I don't see the relevance of 'where EVT_CODE=100 and 104' since you don't quote them in your desired output, surely it's just min and max ev_created_dt grouped by txn_id?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can do cnoditional aggregation:

```
select t.*, te.evt_created_dt_100, te.evt_created_dt_104
from transaction t
inner join (
    select txn_id
        max(case when evt_code = 100 then evt_created_dt end) as evt_created_dt_100,
        max(case when evt_code = 104 then evt_created_dt end) as evt_created_dt_104
    from transaction_event_log_info
    where evt_code in (100, 104)
    group by txn_id
) te on te.txn_id = t.txn_id
```

In very recent versions of MySQL, this would be more efficiently phrased with a lateral join:

```
select t.*, te.*
from transaction t
cross join lateral (
    select
        max(case when te.evt_code = 100 then te.evt_created_dt end) as evt_created_dt_100,
        max(case when te.evt_code = 104 then te.evt_created_dt end) as evt_created_dt_104
    from transaction_event_log_info te
    where te.evt_code in (100, 104) and te.txn_id = t.txn_id
) te
```

If you want to allow transactions that have none of the two events, you would change the `inner join` to a `left join` - and the `cross join lateral (...) te` to a `left join lateral (...) te on true`.